# Permission denied to access property "document" - JS get height of new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to resize my body window after load iframe content to avoid scrollbar. I read about XSS so i know that properties of foreign domain is not accessible, but I wondering is possible to workaround only to get or calculate only height attribute?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: any workaround would be a bug

Comment: Your page is the one that has the iframe or the one that appears in the iframe?

Comment: From what I know it is definately not possible to access any DOM-content from a foreign domain. However, you can use proxys (f.e. mod_proxy from apache2) to pass these foreign domains through yours and simulate the same domain.

Comment: My page has the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help:

- To get the height of the **document** (the content on the page, which has a minimum height of the viewport) use `$(document).height()`.
- To get the height of the **browser window** use `$(window).height()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After load the iframe both heights are the same as before load iframe. So I can't calculate new height.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the iframe to fill your window using css:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" src="http://jakopo87.altervista.org" />
```